# Delivering Git branches for testing

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am using Git for development and rather simple workflow. I have two remote branches: "testing" and "staging". I develop feature in a local branch, merge it to "testing" to deliver feature for testing by tester. As feature is tested I merge local branch to "staging".

Important workflow condition is that we have no releases - we have to deploy features separately.

It works just perfect until conflicts.

My workflow considers I have to deliver same feature for testing several times during feature development because of permanent conditions changing.

The problem is that in case I had 5 feature deliveries for testing and got merge conflict at first delivery, I have to solve conflicts again for all left 4 feature deliveries to keep my branch isolated. The worst thing is that all 5 conflicts I got are the same (the same pieces of code get conflicted) in most cases.

Is there a way to solve conflicts once upon first merging? How do you deliver your branches for testing by another person?

Any help and ideas are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this [post on rerere](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html).  It'll help save you the headache of dealing with the same conflicts over and over.

Answer (score 0):

If the conflicts happens when delivering to the same remote repo, it would be best for that delivery to be done by an integrator at the remote repo (git pull), in order to activate [`git.rerere`](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html).

That will enable the repo to remember a conflict resolution, and to apply that same resolution to any similar conflict, when the other 4 features are pulled in `testing` branch.

Comment: Cool, exactly. rerere will do everything easier. Thank you so much, VonC